# How can I improve this nested loop?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to do a fuzzy match of records in two Account table using .NET Entity Framework.
I wrote some code like this but it has bad performance like 1 min a record.

```
ARSalesforceEntities arsf = new ARSalesforceEntities();   //dbcontext
Salesforce_FFEntities ffsf = new Salesforce_FFEntities();  //dbcontext
var araccounts = arsf.Accounts;           //dbset contains 400000 records
var ffaccounts = ffsf.Accounts;           //dbset contains 6000 records
IDCONV byName = new IDCONV();  
IDCONV byAddress = new IDCONV();
foreach (var ffaccount in ffaccounts)
{

    Console.WriteLine(++count);
    foreach (var araccount in araccounts)//this line goes every slow like 1 min
    {
```

Basically, I am comparing the records in two tables with complicated logic.
How can I greatly improve the performance of the code? 
Thank you

Comment: How complicated are we talking about?

Comment: Without seeing the "complicated logic", its hard to give any advice.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find the bottlenecks?

Comment: You know are executing the inner loop logic 2,400,000,000 times? It's not going to be fast..

Comment: You might be better-off converting this into a sproc and running it directly on the database server. EF is nice, but it's still not great for processing tasks like this.

Comment: Ideally you'd avoid the need to compare every account in one database with every account in another database.  If you really, really need to do this, then it's just an inherently expensive operation and you'll need to live with that.  If what you're doing doesn't actually require you to get the cross product of these two sets then perhaps you could do a lot better.

Comment: @Dai The two tables are in different databases though.  And even a database is likely to struggle performing a cross product of two large tables.

Comment: @Servy SQL Server sprocs can work with other databases, even other servers (or any ODBC source, in fact).

Comment: I want to match the records in two tables based on the field 'Phone' or 'name' or 'address'.  Those fields are not perfectly matched. I have to use algorithms like 'Levenshtein' to find the matched fields than records.

Comment: @Dai Sure, it's possible, but it's not going to perform particularly better than doing things on the application's side, precisely because all of the data still isn't in a single location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
var ffaccounts = ffsf.Accounts;
```

is what's hitting you hard. You're basically assigning the `IQueryable` to a variable which, when accessed in your inner loop, re-queries the database everytime. I imagine simply adding `ToList()` on the end will drastically improve your performance:

```
var ffaccounts = ffsf.Accounts.ToList();
```

That's assuming of course that it's acceptable to materialise the 6000 rows into memory.

If not, then you might want to consider writing the logic in SQL and doing all the work in the DB instead...

Comment: I tried this first but it's out of memory. If I just query a part of the table rather than all columns, but same number of rows, is it possible overcome this?

Comment: Do you need to make modifications to the 6000 entities at all? If no then load them `AsNoTracking()`. That should reduce the memory footprint somewhat.

Comment: No, I don't need to make modification to either of the two table. I just want to find the matched records and insert the IDs of them into another table

Comment: So best bet is to add `.AsNoTracking()` to the first assignment and `.AsNoTracking().ToList()` to the second. That should keep the memory usage under control and minimise the performance cost of loading the smaller set of rows.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need. My account is banned because of this question....

Comment: @Singed if you're banned, it won't be because of a single question. If you go back and edit a few of your old questions to improve them you can probably get yourself unbanned. Maybe post some good answers too.